# Creating a Tkinter class and waiting for a return value

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a tkinter class:

```
class DBCreatorWin():
    def closeWindow(self):
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Ilmiont SQLite Database Manager", "This window cannot be closed.\nEnter a database name and press Continue.")

    def returnName(self):
        dbName = self.entry.get()
        self.window.destroy()
        return dbName

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Toplevel()
        self.window.transient(tkRoot)
        self.window.grab_set()
        self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.window.title("Ilmiont SQLite Database Manager")
        self.window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.closeWindow)

        self.label = Label(self.window, text="Enter the name of the database to be created: ")
        self.entry = Entry(self.window, width=30)
        self.button = Button(self.window, text="Continue", command=self.returnName)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

I want to create an instance of this class within my main code and wait for the return value. The user types a name into the entry field and presses the Continue button. At that point, the value should be returned to where the class was originally instantiated. How do I go about this? I can't seem to make it work in a normal way and am new to tkinter.

Thanks in advance,
Ilmiont

Comment: The normal flow of code will not continue after calling `mainloop` until the window is closed. If you want the GUI to stay open, you will have to call the code logic from within the GUI. Without a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say what you're currently doing wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look into using something like the [`easygui`](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) module which isn't event-driven.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The basic idea is to use a tkinter method to wait for a specific event before returning. Tkinter provides two methods to do just that: [wait_window](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_window-method) and [wait_variable](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.wait_variable-method).  The most common method is to open a window and then wait for it to be destroyed. Some good examples can be found on the effbot site, on a page titled [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm).

Here's a simple illustration. It's not production-ready, but illustrates the general idea. At the very least you'll want to add a grab on the dialog so that you can't interact with the main window while the dialog is open, since you said you want the dialog to be modal.

```
import Tkinter as tk
class MyDialog(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.toplevel = tk.Toplevel(parent)
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        label = tk.Label(self.toplevel, text="Pick something:")
        om = tk.OptionMenu(self.toplevel, self.var, "one", "two","three")
        button = tk.Button(self.toplevel, text="OK", command=self.toplevel.destroy)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        om.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        button.pack()

    def show(self):
        self.toplevel.deiconify()
        self.toplevel.wait_window()
        value = self.var.get()
        return value


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Click me!", command=self.on_click)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, width=80)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.button.pack(pady=20)

    def on_click(self):
        result = MyDialog(self).show()
        self.label.configure(text="your result: %s" % result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It works well. After some additional hunting, I came across tkSimpleDialog.askstring which actually solves my problem very well.

Answer (score -2):

You can't.

The whole way the tkinter works is with callbacks. The command that you're using is the callback and you'll have to use the value inside the class. Here is an example:

```
def do_stuf(self):
    tkMessageBox.showinfo("Foo", returnName())

                  ....................

self.button = Button(self.window, text="Continue", command=self.do_stuff)
```