# Tkinter Message box with cancel button only

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Can I create a tkinter [messagebox](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.messagebox.html#module-tkinter.messagebox) that only has a 'cancel' button and nothing else (no 'ok' button or anything)? If yes how?

Comment: in your link is url to source code - you can see in source code if it accept option which can change text on button. OR you can get this source code and create own messagebox.

Comment: see how to create own dialog  window: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the messagebox does not support a cancel-only option. I recommend you re-word the message so that an "ok" button makes sense in the given context. Otherwise, you will have to create your own dialog with a `Toplevel`, button, and any other widgets you might want.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the mainloop until the dialog I make is pressed (that's the real problem with me making my own dialog)

Comment: @DYD: yes, use the method `wait_window` which will not return until the dialog is destroyed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29498445/7432